# How does public-key cryptography work?

Tags: cryptography, public-key

and what are the differences between conventional cryptography and public-key cryptography?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how does public key cryptography work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853889/how-does-public-key-cryptography-work)

Comment: -1 A quick trip to google and wikipedia would provide all these basic details (and much more). The knowledge learned from that -- even if very basic -- would both answer this question and provide a foundation to ask a much better question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, public-key cryptography means that you have a "public/private" pair of keys. The public key can be used to encrypt messages, but not decrypt them. The private key is, as the name suggests, secret, and can be used to decrypt the messages.

Typical usage goes like this:

- Alice creates a public/private key pair.
- Alice sends her public key to Bob, keeping the private key in a safe location.
- Bob sends the encrypted message to Alice.
- Alice receives the message and uses her private key to decrypt it.

Usage examples of asymmetric encryption:

- In situations where no trusted channel can be established for exchanging symmetric keys (e.g. HTTPS): because the public key cannot decrypt, it is safe to send it over an untrusted connection
- When the same public key needs to be used by more than one user (e.g. encrypted e-mail): even though all the senders use the same public key, they cannot use it to decrypt any messages; only the recipient has the private key

Answer (score 1):

You should probably re-phrase your question:

Public-key cryptography uses an asymmetric approach where the key used to encrypt and the key used to decrypt a message are not the same. Here is a description of the RSA asymmetric algorithm: [RSA (asymmetric cryptography)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA)

There is probably no "conventional crypthography". What you probably mean are symmetric algorithms where both keys are the same. [Symmetric key algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm)